# php prestashop cookie

Tags: php, prestashop

how to access prestashop cookie?
the directory structure islike this
/
|
|-index.php
|
|-prestashop/
   |
   |-(presta shop files)

I manage to do a login from the index.php.
but i cannot access the cookie to check if the user logged in or not.
any way to check it or get the user name

Comment: What is the `index.php` that is outside of prestahop? You want the user to log in before accessing your store?

Answer (score 1):

For Prestashop 1.6 its different now, there is no `$smarty` and no `$cookie`, all in Context.

How to access the Context?

From inside a Controller subclass, an AdminTab subclass or a Module subclass, the Context should be called with this shortcut: `$this->context`.

From anywhere else, you can get the `Context` instance by calling `Context::getContext()`.

Old way

```
$cookie->id_lang;
```

New way

```
$this->context->language->id;
```

More about this in docs here http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Using+the+Context+Object#UsingtheContextObject-WhatistheContextobject?

Answer (score 0):

Prestashop maintains a global $cookie variable which is an object of type `Cookie`. As long as you're bootstrapping Prestashop in your external index.php file, then you should be able to access it:

```
function myfunction()
{
  global $cookie;

  if ($cookie->isLogged)
    echo 'Here be dragons.';
}
```

Without knowing how you're accessing the Prestashop core to perform the login though it's hard to give specific advice...

Comment: Hi @PaulCampbell, thanks for your answer. I am trying to find a way to initialize PS within my CI site, and am unable to find a way that works. Any idea how to do this in CI 2.1.4 and PS 1.5.6? (Sorry for hijacking this question/answer with a "me too" type comment...)